# how to insert labels into a vector

Tags: r

I have a numeric structure from a ColMeans() like this:

```
1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10         11         12         13         14         15         16         17         18         19 
0.01293814 0.96154639 0.99824742 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 
20         21         22         23         24         25         26         27         28         29         30         31         32         33         34         35         36         37         38 
1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 
39         40         41         42         43         44         45         46         47         48         49         50         51         52         53 
1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000
```

I am trying to flatten this structure to something like:

```
1 0.01293814 2 0.96154639 3 0.99824742 4 1.00000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my test vector:

```
> 1:3 -> foo
> 6:4 -> names(foo)
> foo
6 5 4 
1 2 3
```

You can first use `rbind` on the names and the values:

```
> rbind(as.numeric(names(foo)), as.numeric(foo)) -> bar
> bar
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    6    5    4
[2,]    1    2    3
```

Now, turn the matrix back into a vector, removing the second dimension:

```
> as.vector(bar) -> bar
> bar
[1] 6 1 5 2 4 3
```

You can of course put some of these steps into the same expression, I did it step by step to make obvious what is happening.

As far as I am aware, the `rbind` followed by flattening it back to a vector is something of an R idiom for "zipping"? Someone with deeper knowledge of R will probably correct me on this.

Comment: @akrun No problem, as many question here on SO, if we wanted to help we would probably have to ask questions like "but why do you need to do this" and say stuff like "there is a better way to avoid this problem"... :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `paste`

```
v2 <- paste(names(v1), v1, collapse=" ")
v2 
#[1] "1 0.01293814 2 0.96154639 3 0.99824742"
```

If we need a `vector` of values

```
scan(text=v2, what=numeric(), quiet=TRUE)
#[1] 1.00000000 0.01293814 2.00000000 0.96154639 3.00000000 0.99824742
```

or we can `rbind` as showed in the other post and just do `c`

```
c(rbind(names(v1), v1))
#[1] "1"          "0.01293814" "2"          "0.96154639" "3"          "0.99824742"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- setNames(c(0.01293814, 0.96154639, 0.99824742), 1:3)
```

Comment: I am not following you... I am trying to incorporate the labels into the vector

Comment: @user299791 The output showed is not clear.  Is it a single string?

Comment: yes, it is supposed to be a single vector, where you have the label and the value the label and the value, the label and the value and so on...

Comment: You realize that in your `paste` + `scan` solution you are writing numbers into a string and then parsing that string back into numbers, right?